# running CFA in lavaan - displaying correlation between latent variables

Tags: r, correlation

I have run a Confirmatory Factor Analysis and I now would like to apply the Fornell/Larcker Criterion. For doing so, I need the correlation between the latent variables. How can I display/retrieve the correlation between the latent variables?

I have tried the following commands generating an output:

- `standardizedSolution(fit)`
- `summary(fit, fit.measures=TRUE)`
- `lavInspect(fit,"standardized")`

But none of these commands generates a "phi" (covariance between latent variables. Thus, I have two questions:

1) So, does anyone know how to display latent variables of a confirmatory factor analysis in r?

2) Take a look at the output of lavInspect(fit,"standardized") (see the link at the bottom of the text). Instead of a "phi" it generates a "$psi". Does that "psi" may be a "phi"? Because the matrix it generates looks like a correlation matrix

Here is the code:

```
#packages
library(lavaan)
library(readr)

CNCS<- read_delim("Desktop/20190703 Full Launch/Regressionen/Factor analysis/CNCS -47 Reversed.csv",
       ";", escape_double = FALSE, trim_ws = TRUE)

View(CNCS)
library(carData)
library(car)

CNCS.model <-

'AttitudeTowardsTheDeal =~ Q42_1 + Q42_2 + Q42_3

SubjectiveNormsImportance =~ Q43_r1 + Q43_r2 + Q43_r3 + Q43_r4

SubjectiveNormsFavour =~ Q44_r1 + Q44_r2 + Q44_r3 + Q44_r4

EaseOfPurchasing =~ Q45_r1 + Q45_r2 + Q45_r3 + Q45_r4 + Q45_r5 + Q45_r6

SE =~ Q3_r1 + Q3_r2 + Q3_r3 + Q4_r4

Consumer Innovativeness =~ Q4_r1 + Q4_r2 + Q4_r3 + Q4_r4 + Q4_r5

Purchase Intention =~ Q41moeglich_1 + Q41gewiss_1 + Q1wahrscheinlich_1 + Q41vorauss_1'


fit <- cfa(CNCS.model, data=CNCS)
summary(fit, fit.measures=TRUE)
lavInspect(fit,"standardized")
standardizedSolution(fit)
```

Partial OUTPUT of `lavInspect(fit,"standardized")`

[Please follow the link to the screenshot of the partial output of lavInspect()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fjce1.png)

Comment: Hi Marco. Could you please supply your full used code and packages in your question. That could help others solve the issue better.

Comment: I think you will be better served by asking this question on CrossValidated (stats.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Thanks for the tip, January. Here's the post on CrossValidated https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/417136/running-cfa-in-lavaan-displaying-correlation-between-latent-variables

Comment: @January, my question was put off-topic at CrossValidated, so it remains here.

Comment: LOL :-) I'm sorry about that. I'm afraid that it won't be easy to get a better response here, but I cross my fingers.

Comment: the PSI in `lavInspect(fit,"standardized")` is the correlation matrix. Also, have a look at `summary(fit)` which does give you the covariances and variances among/of the (latent) variables. Adding the option `summary(fit, standardized = TRUE)` also gives you the columns `Std.lv` which are the exact same entries as `Psi`. Also have a look at the [lavaan tutorial](http://lavaan.ugent.be/tutorial/tutorial.pdf)

Comment: @Tom, thanks for your answer. Are you sure that "PSI" is the correlation matrix? Because I confronted 'lavInspect(fit,"standardized")' with the values of of the columns 'Std.lv' of 'summary(fit, standardized=TRUE)' and it says that these are the COVARIANCES.

My point is: how I can retrieve the correlations of the latent variables?

Comment: @Tom, I think I got it. As you wrote summary(fit) provides the covariances and variances of the latent variables. When dividing the covariances with the square of the variances I obtain the correlation of the respective latent variables. The latter is represented in the correlation matrix PSI or in Std.lv . Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the `cfa` example given in the manual as

```
library(lavaan)
## The famous Holzinger and Swineford (1939) example
HS.model <- ' visual  =~ x1 + x2 + x3
              textual =~ x4 + x5 + x6
              speed   =~ x7 + x8 + x9 '

fit <- cfa(HS.model, data=HolzingerSwineford1939)
```

and include the standardized fit in the summary with

```
summary(fit, standardized = TRUE)
```

obtaining

```
...

Latent Variables:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)   Std.lv  Std.all
  visual =~                                                             
    x1                1.000                               0.900    0.772
    x2                0.554    0.100    5.554    0.000    0.498    0.424
    x3                0.729    0.109    6.685    0.000    0.656    0.581
  textual =~                                                            
    x4                1.000                               0.990    0.852
    x5                1.113    0.065   17.014    0.000    1.102    0.855
    x6                0.926    0.055   16.703    0.000    0.917    0.838
  speed =~                                                              
    x7                1.000                               0.619    0.570
    x8                1.180    0.165    7.152    0.000    0.731    0.723
    x9                1.082    0.151    7.155    0.000    0.670    0.665

Covariances:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)   Std.lv  Std.all
  visual ~~                                                             
    textual           0.408    0.074    5.552    0.000    0.459    0.459
    speed             0.262    0.056    4.660    0.000    0.471    0.471
  textual ~~                                                            
    speed             0.173    0.049    3.518    0.000    0.283    0.283

Variances:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)   Std.lv  Std.all
   .x1                0.549    0.114    4.833    0.000    0.549    0.404
   .x2                1.134    0.102   11.146    0.000    1.134    0.821
   .x3                0.844    0.091    9.317    0.000    0.844    0.662
   .x4                0.371    0.048    7.779    0.000    0.371    0.275
   .x5                0.446    0.058    7.642    0.000    0.446    0.269
   .x6                0.356    0.043    8.277    0.000    0.356    0.298
   .x7                0.799    0.081    9.823    0.000    0.799    0.676
   .x8                0.488    0.074    6.573    0.000    0.488    0.477
   .x9                0.566    0.071    8.003    0.000    0.566    0.558
    visual            0.809    0.145    5.564    0.000    1.000    1.000
    textual           0.979    0.112    8.737    0.000    1.000    1.000
    speed             0.384    0.086    4.451    0.000    1.000    1.000
```

You find the entries of the **covariance** matrix in the `Covariances:` and `Variances:` sections respectively in column `Estimate` and the entries of the **correlation** matrix in column `Std.lv`.

Note that `inspect` or rather `lavInspect` provides the argument `what` which by default is specified with `"free"`. Taken from the manual, the three relevant other options are

- `"est"`: A list of model matrices. The values represent the estimated model parameters. Aliases: "estimates", and "x".
- `"std"`: A list of model matrices. The values represent the (completely) standardized model parameters (the variances of both the observed and the latent variables are set to unity). Aliases: "std.all", "standardized".
- `"std.lv"`: A list of model matrices. The values represent the standardized model parameters (only the variances of the latent variables are set to unity.)

which refer to the summary columns `Estimate` `Std.lv` and `Std.all`. Further try the following line

```
cov2cor(lavInspect(fit, what = "est")$psi)
```

In case of any remaining doubt, I recommend you consult the [tutorial](http://lavaan.ugent.be/tutorial/tutorial.pdf), the packages [support infrastructure](https://groups.google.com/d/forum/lavaan) or the [homepage](http://lavaan.ugent.be/).