# Correlation between latent variables

Tags: r, statistics, correlation, r-lavaan

I used the CFA to analysis the hypothesis stipulates that the variables violation and less safety have a negative impact on self-efficacy belief of individuals. to carry out this i use the regression multiple and i used cfa function of lavaan package.

The model is defined as follow:

`model1= violation =~ va1+va2+va3+va4 less_safety =~ LS1+LS2+LS3+LS5 elf_efficacy =~ EE1+EE2+EE3+EE4 elf_efficacy ~ violation + less_safety # here how the test will be carried out`

`library(lavaan)`

`fit_model1<-cfa(model1, data=Mydata)`

To obtain coefficients

`parameterEstimates(fit_model1,standardized=TRUE)`

Moreover, i used inspect function to get the correlation but i obtain the correlation between Items( va1,va2,va3,va4,LS1,LS2,LS3,LS5,EE1,EE2,EE3,EE4).

`inspect(fit_model1,"cov.ov")`

My question is it possible to obtain the correlation between latent variables (violation, self_efficacity and less_safety) as shown on this table:

| Variable | M (Means) | standard deviation | violation | less_safety |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| violation | MeanV | sd_V |  |  |
| less_safety | MeanLS | sd_LS | Correlation(V,LS)** |  |
| self_efficacity | MeanSE | sd_SE | Correlation(V,SE)** | Correlation(LS,SE)* |

thank you very much for your help

Comment: This may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56973348/running-cfa-in-lavaan-displaying-correlation-between-latent-variables

Answer (score 0):

> is it possible to obtain the correlation between latent variables

```
lavInspect(fit_model1,"cor.ov")
```

If you additionally want to test whether each is different from zero, you can use the standardized solution:

```
standardizedSolution(fit_model1)
```

or simply fit a model with standardized latent variables.

```
fit_model1 <- cfa(model1, data = Mydata, std.lv = TRUE)
```

The lavaan tutorial is a good start:

https://lavaan.ugent.be/tutorial